# Draw a polyline based on user click and/or current user location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-polyline

Currently I'm building a webapp to draw my city public transport routes (Which aren't in Google Maps). I'm using encoded polylines to display them and have created a `<ul>` from which they can be manually selected. It works fine but need to add more functionality.

What I want is that when a user clicks a point on the map or uses the geolocation function, the routes (As predefined polylines) that get pass nearby get drawn.

I've read the [containsLocation()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation) documentation but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Is there a specific library that I'm missing to do this?

Already searched a lot and can't find what I want.

Currently this is the code that draws the polyline (When called from a `<li onclick='drawfunction()';>` element):

```
    function (drawingfunction) {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

    var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath('encodedpolyline'); 

    var decodedLevels = decodeLevels('encodedlevels');
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what problem you are having now. Are you not be able to detect the onClick event, or no drawing after onClick function is called?

Comment: No, I have those two solved @ztan, what I want to do is being able to draw all of the pre-defined polylines that fall beneath a radius around user location, or if location is not available, a user right click on a "Routes nearby here".

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to check out the [`google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly) function.

Assuming your route [`Polyline`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline)s are in a `routes` array:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
  var matching = google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(
      location, routes[i], TOLERANCE);

  routes[i].setOptions({
    strokeColor: matching ? MATCHING_COLOR : DEFAULT_COLOR,
    strokeOpacity: matching ? 1 : .7
  });
}
```

You'll want to play around with the tolerance parameter to find a suitable size for your click target.

It might be quite slow if you have a lot of routes (or complex routes). If it is, then you'll want to investigate a data structure like a [quad tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) to narrow down the routes before calling `isLocationOnEdge`.

Comment: Actually I'm using encoded polylines, but don't know how to get the decoded values into a usable array.

Comment: Tried to achieve it but couldn't make it work, Is any demo out there where I can see how it works?